# Overlaying one PDF over another

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am working on a new in-house automated artwork workflow system. The new system delivers a stepped up PDF ready for offset print. The artwork is black only with barcodes and variable data text. There might be between 4 and 50 stepped up artworks per SRA3 sheet.

However, the new system is unable to add tick marks, gripper marks and other information around the edge of the sheet that our production teams would like. Our attempts to add these are not always fit for purpose as the of the shelf software used to generate the variable data was intended for thermal printers.

What would be better is if we had the tick marks saved on another series of template PDF's. We could then superimpose these on the automated artwork.

We are talking about 100's of PDF's per day and we would need this process to be a simple and as possible requiring little skill on the part of the operator or even automated/scripted.

I have read a similar post where adding watermark with Acrobat was recommended. This worked a treat for me but considering the high volumes of artwork, even if made into a Acrobat Batch Process/Action, this would be too involved.

Any ideas welcome: Rip Software, AppleScript, MSDOS!!! Whatever!

Cheers

Tim